# how to check if the doc file is actual or fake

Tags: php, html

I managed to check for the image file whether it is fake or not when user manually change the file extension name when uploading by using the code in this website https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp. My question is how to do the same thing for doc file?Is it possible ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload2" id="fileToUpload2">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload2"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload2"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: So what you want now? You can use the same for docs as well

Comment: use PHPWord, if the uploaded file can be loaded by PHPWord then it is valid. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: The code in the question might not work as expected. Please read the notice in the [getimagesize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) page of the manual.

Comment: but i've tried changing the file extension like .pdf to .jpg and click the submit button.It echo back the right thing which is "File is not an image"

Comment: The notice says: "it **may** be incorrectly detected", not "it **will** be incorrectly detected". I would heed the advice given.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in the same way you can validate the doc/docx file.

```
$allowed_ext = array('doc', 'docx');
$filename = $_FILES['fileToUpload2']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (!in_array($ext, $allowed))
{
    echo "File is not valid doc file.";
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo) only gets the file extension, it doesn't check what the file contains.

Comment: Thq question was related to checking the file extension not file content.

Comment: Well, we clearly have a difference of opinion on that.